# XML Creation, pulling a value if existing within an external excel based template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, excel

I have tried this in ruby and here is my code:

```
 require 'roo'
 require 'roo-xls'
 require 'byebug'

 file_name = ARGV.first || "test_Abnahme_Meld.xls"

 excel_file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("./#{file_name}", extension: :xls)

 xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: 'UTF-8') do |xml|
 xml.test("version": "2.0","xmlns": 
 "https://www.test.uk/siml/2.0/final") do
 xml.Data("language": "GBR") do

  excel_file.each_with_index do |row, index|
    next if index == 0

    xml.Aktion("teilnehmerkennung": "60000592", "teilnehmerkennwort": 
  "MIGIND05") do
      xml.Teilnehmerreferenz "ref#{row[1].to_i}GRB2"
      xml.MeldungVertragsdaten("version":"1.0") do
        xml.Meldemerkmal("merkmalcode":"K4") do
          xml.Kontonummer "#{row[11].round}"
          xml.Datum "#{row[12]}"
          xml.Betrag("waehrung": 'EUR') { |e| e << "#{row[13].round}" }
          xml.Ratenzahl "#{row[14].round}"
          xml.Ratenart "#{row[15]}"
        end
          xml.Meldeart ("neumeldung") do
          end
          xml.Verbraucherdaten do
            xml.Vorname "#{row[3]}"
            xml.Nachname "#{row[2]}"
            xml.Geschlecht "#{row[4]}"
            xml.Geburtsdatum "#{row[6]}"
            xml.Land "#{row[7]}"
            xml.AktuelleAdresse do
              xml.Strasse "#{row[10]}"
              xml.PLZ "#{row[8].round}"
              xml.Ort "#{row[9]}"
            end
          end
        end
    end
    end
   end 
  end
 end.to_xml

 File.open("output.xml", "w") { |file| file.write(xml) }
```

Data sample:

```
vorname nachname geschlecht geburtsdatum land
George   Jones      m         30/10/1994 PRT
Tom      Kaye       m         19/04/2000
```

This refers to a separate excel sheet where I am referencing to column numbers 2,3,4 etc.

Where I have Land row 5 I want to include this xml item only if there is data for Land in Column 7 on the xls.

I can generate the xml but it's currently putting in land populating land as blank when in fact I do not want it to exist if there is no value in the corresponding row. for example row 2 of the data sample does not contain a land. Can you advise please?

Expected XML Sample for including land and not including land:

```
<PLZ>74544</PLZ>
<Land>PRT</Land>
<Ort>Michelbach</Ort>

<PLZ>74544</PLZ>
<Ort>Michelbach</Ort>
```

Comment: Ruby, I have added a complete code sample.

Comment: Can you do something like `xml.Land "#{row[7]}" unless row[7].empty?`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still have access to Ruby methods within the blocks, so could you not use something like:

```
xml.Land(row[7]) if row[7].present?
```

Might not work in the Nokigiri block - let me know if not and I'll remove the answer.

(Also, do you need to interpolate all of the results? I've removed it from this example, though obviously feel free to pop it back in if needed.)

Comment: Hi unfortunately the above statement did not work and produced an error

Comment: Hey @GeorgeH - what was the error? If you edit it into your question and give me a nudge, I'll take a look. Sure we can get there with this!